# No internet in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet

I am dual booting Windows and Ubuntu 22.04. After booting there's no internet connection and a question mark is being shown where the ethernet symbol is supposed to be. On Windows the internet works normally, so it has to be a software issue. Also, it's not just the ethernet. Even USB internet and wireless internet is not working.

I did nothing too significant recently except for installing Waydroid, but there's no internet. At first I was able to fix it by following a tutorial that told me to type `sudo dhclient <device>`, so I typed `sudo dhclient enp2s0` It worked then, but now it doesn't work anymore. One tutorial told me to type something that I don't remember, but I do remember that the output was `network-manager.system does not exist`.

Results of `ip a` :

[image]

Result in text:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:1c:c9:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 83741sec preferred_lft 83741sec
    inet6 fe80::50e3:f1ee:4394:ba2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.15.134/23 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 dead:beef:2::1184/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7950:9f36:4231:c113/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you post `ip a`. Is it your network, do you use a static ip, is it ipv6, does the router handle DHCP?

Comment: @pbhj sure. Just did it now. Check the question. I use a static ip ipv4 and yes, my router does handle dhcp. It's probably not my router though because as I said, I dualboot ubuntu and windows and in windows the internet is working just fine.

Comment: Wowzers, you've got a complex system - is the IP the same as you use under Windows? I'd guess it's a route issue (system doesn't know which IP to send traffic on), I'm on mobile, will take a look later.

Comment: @pbhj yeah...I use my ip (192.168.1.3) for both windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Your arp table is getting two unique macs for the same IP address at your gateway device. Why not choose a different IP address for each OS you boot?

Comment: @darnleyc any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Could you [edit] and copy and paste the result text (enclosed with triple backticks: \`\`\` ) instead of posting the screenshot? I'm afraid the image is a bit blurry and kind of difficult to read.

Comment: @AndrewT. I wanted to do that earlier only but then, as the internet was unavailable, I couldn't do it. I didn't find any way of fixing the issue for a long time so I just reinstalled ubuntu and it all seems to be working again. But this might be an issue for other people too so I'm keeping this question open. Anyways, I've edited the question to include the result of IP a: